# Is it possible to make a cross domain request from https to http in IE?

Tags: wcf, internet-explorer, jquery, https, cross-domain

We are trying to access a local self-hosted WCF service from the browser.
The WCF service is located at `http://localhost/myWcf`.
The browser is running a website which is located at `https://some.www.com`.

We have enabled CORS and added CORS header to the hosted WCF. Access to the WCF service is done using jQuery’s $.ajax call. All browsers are working fine when not using SSL and we’re getting to the “success” callback.
When switching to SSL, IE is the only one that fails to make the request – “Access is denied”. We moved the website to the trusted sites section and basically allowed everything there and still no go. We’re using IE11/10 and we've tried previous versions through its emulator. None of them allows us to make that request.

**We can address a picture that located in http from https like this:**

```
<img src="http://asdasd">
```

but we try to use javascript it fails:

```
var img = new Image(); 
img.src="http://asdasd";
```

What are we missing? Is it really impossible to make a cross domain request from https to http in IE?

Comment: You can address the picture because there's no single origin policy for images in IE, there are origin policies for secure to non-secure XHR though.

Comment: @DanielWaters is there any way to make it work?

Comment: PKolos answer below would work but there's a reason origin policies exist, especially for secure connections. Is there no way of you making the HTTP endpoint HTTPS instead via a self signed certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check jsonp:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.id = 'dynScript';
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://localhost/myWcf';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

JSONP is a great away to get around cross-domain scripting errors.